# Forcing a 3D function to converge to a specific value

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to make a certain function which is similar to the function

$$f(x,y)=xy$$

except it is cut off to prevent $f \rightarrow \infty$ and $f \rightarrow -\infty$. My current attempt at this is introducing a cutoff functions

$$ f_c(x) = 0.5 - 0.5\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)$$
$$ f_c(y) = 0.5 - 0.5\sin\left(\frac{y-a}{b}\right)$$

and multiplying to get

$$f(x,y)=xyf_c(x)f_c(y)$$

which is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fotrk.jpg) in 3D and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHPAk.jpg) in 2D.

I am doing this because I want to approximate $f(x,y)=xy$ in a certain vicinity (in this case, $a+b$) but I want it to *smoothly* cutoff past a certain point. My solution is not good for me because I don't want the function to return back to zero. I want it to to stay at the maximum and minimum it reached.

For example, in the 2D plot I would like the top right to stay yellow, the bottom right to stay blue, the bottom left to stay yellow, and the top left to stay blue for $x \rightarrow \infty $ and $y \rightarrow \infty $. This means that the function converges to constant values on each side. I hope this conveys the type of shape I am trying to make.

I've tried other cutoff functions ($coth$, etc.) without any success. Does anyone have any idea on a different cutoff function to use, or a method to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+min(1-e**(-1000*(x**2%2By**2)),+x*y))?
$$z = \min\Big{(}c-ae^{-b(x^2+y^2)},\ xy\Big{)}$$
You can probably choose the constants $a$ and $b$ such that $xy$ and the inverted Gaussian match all partial derivatives at their intersection, thus making a smooth (differentiable) connection. The larger you make $b$, the more $z$ will behave like $xy$ while $z<<c$. This function will not exceed $c$.

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exactly what I need except this function diverges to negative infinity. Is there a way so that it converges to $-c $ on those sides, while still converging to $+c $ on the other sides?

Comment: Try taking $\max(\cdot)$ of the expression I gave with something like $pe^{-q(x^2+y^2)}-c$ since that function will never go below c. Basically I'm just taking min and max with functions that are radial, smooth, have some good parametric freedom, and asymptote towards a cut-off. I guess gaussian fits the bill